# Printing initials of First, Middle, Last name

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

This is the first time for me using java and I have been trying to solve a problem. The problem was to print two letters from each name(First, middle, last). But this has to be done with indexOf and substring methods.
I tried as much as I can with a sample development example in textbook, but it's too hard for me.
Ex) if my full name is Amit Kugar Chandra the output should be
ChKuAm.
I tried getting the user to input his name one word at a time, but is there any there a possible way to get the export especially two letters with one uppercase another lowercase?

```
package test;

import java.util.*;

public class Ch2Monogram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String name;
                
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        
        System.out.print("Enter your full name(first, middle, last): ");
        
        name = scanner.next();
        
        String first = name.substring(0, 2);
        
        name = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ")+1, name.length());
        
        String middle = name.substring(0, 2);
        
        String last = name.substring(0, 2);
        
        System.out.println("Name entered: " + last + middle + first);
        scanner.close();
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you performing a substring of uninitialized string `name`? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: to print two letters from each name(first, middle, last). I put 'String name;'  because the example from the textbook also put the same thing

Comment: you have to move your input part to first before splitting the `name`

Comment: Thank you so much, and i have one more question which the String last. I can correctly get the output I wanted for first and middle name letters, but the last two letters don't come out. The output is here ;Enter your full name(first, middle, last): Amit Kugar Chandra
Name entered: KuKuAm

Comment: You're correctly removing the first name from `string`, but then you don't remove the middle name, so your lines which get the middle and last name do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what is 'removing the middle name' Can you explain more about it if you can?